# Can't write text into file

Tags: java

I want to write int into text file.
I wrote this code

```
public static void WriteInt(int i,String fileName){
    File directory = new File("C:\\this\\");
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File("C\\"+fileName);
    FileOutputStream fOut = null;

    try {
        //Create the stream pointing at the file location
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(directory, fileName));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    try {

        osw.write(i);


        osw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But in output file I have no int , just one symbol.
Any ideas to do it?

Comment: @Leo - Most probably a *typo*

Comment: Changed to C:\\ but it still don't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be using PrintWriter.print(int)

Writer.write() outputs one character, that's what it's for. Don't get confused by int parameter type. Wrap your osw in PrintWriter, don't forget to close that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 osw.write(i);
```

This line writes the character to the file whose unicode value is `i`

You should use `PrintWriter` to write your integer value.

Answer (score 0):

`OutputStreamWriter` is a stream to print characters.

Try using a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) like this:

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file); 
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw)) {
    pw.print(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that you expected to literally find the number in human-readable format in your file, but the method of the **OutputStreamWriter** you're using (which receives a **int**) expect to receive a **char** representation. Have a look at the [Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) for a reference of what **int** represents which **char**.

If you really wanted you write the number with **characters**, consider using a **PrintWriter** instead of a **OutputStreamWriter**. You could also change your **int** into a String  (**Integer.toString(i)**) and still use your **OutputStreamWriter**